# Background-image me funciona en local pero no en servidor

Tags: css, imagen, scss, background

Cuando visualizo mi web desde local el background si se visualiza, pero al subirlo por FTP no se carga la imagen del background, aún viendo en el inspector de elementos que la ruta está bien indicada. Antes eran .svg, pero las exporté a .png porque leí que svg daba problemas.
Tengo estas líneas en el css:

```
background-image: url("../../assets/img/bg.png"); 
background-color: turquoise;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: Utiliza la ruta completa desde la carpeta de tu proyecto, sin usar `../`, me avisas.